# Issue with Phusion Passenger handling multiple projects with multiple RVM rubies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

Hey I've deployed one of my Rails app in the server using `phusion Passenger(4.0.20)` and `Rails 3.0.3` and Ruby `ruby-1.8.7-p374`. In the same system, we are managing other rails projects also with other Rails and Ruby versions. We are using `RVM` to manage rubies.

Doing rvm list shows:

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p371 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-1.8.7-p374 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p451 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

The project that I've problem while running is using `ruby-1.8.7-p374` and `Rails 3.0.3`. Now when I take the URL, it shows the below given error.
[image]

Restarted apache, restarted passenger, but we are getting issues with `ruby-2.0.0-p451` which we have installed for managing another Rails application.

What could be the reason? Please help :)

Comment: Are you sure your user has access to `rvm`?

Comment: Yes, I have fixed it using `rvm fix-permissions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the project directory and run the below commands one by one:

```
rvm use ruby-1.8.7-p374
gem install bundler passenger
rvm passenger-install-apache2-module
```

This will install passenger along with Apache module, mean while you will be asked to add some configuration changes to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and do it as such.

Create a file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` for your site (something like 'www.virtualx.com') and insert this:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    # Change these 3 lines to suit your project
    RailsEnv production
    ServerName www.virtualx.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my_project/public # Note the 'public' directory
</VirtualHost>
```

and set the `PassengerRuby` option to `ruby-1.8.7-p374`.

Restart Apache service. You are all done.

Now it will work ok.

If you need multiple ruby versions working simultaneously for different projects, then refer [here](http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: There is no need to reinstall Phusion Passenger under a different RVM Ruby or a different gemset. You can install Phusion Passenger with any RVM Ruby and with any gemset, and the result will work with *any other* RVM Ruby/gemset as long as you configure things correctly. See http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#relationship_with_ruby

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a .ruby-version in your project directory? Your project is trying to load `ruby-2.0.0-p451` instead of `ruby-1.8.7-p374`

Have a .ruby-version in your project dir with the set version you want, ie, `ruby-1.8.7-p374` and try.

[Use rvmrc or ruby-version file to set a project gemset with RVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708916/use-rvmrc-or-ruby-version-file-to-set-a-project-gemset-with-rvm)

Comment: When I run `ruby -v` from my project directory, it clearly says that it is using `ruby-1.8.7-p374`. So, that's not the case. Anyway, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Are you running passenger stand alone or with nginx?

Comment: You could see the tags, I'm running passenger with apache module.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed it. Similar issues are reported previously. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470011/rails-rvm-apache-passenger-error-spawnmanager-permissions-denied-in-2-3-11

Comment: I know. I've checked most of references available and then only I tried to post in SO. Thanks :)

Comment: Appreciate your effort done already. Can you share the Apache's config file?

Comment: I've resolved it. I'll post the answer in a short while.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues here:

1. Phusion Passenger is trying to use /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451 as the Ruby interpreter to run your app. But /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451 is a directory, not an executable! Furthermore, you intend to run your app under ruby-1.8.7-p374, not ruby-2.0.0-p451. This means you didn't set your PassengerRuby option correctly. Read http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerRuby to learn how to set this correctly. There's even a section in the manual specifically about how to do this when you're using RVM.
2. As you can see under "User and groups", Phusion Passenger is trying to execute your app as the "nobody" user. This is probably not what you intended! Use [PassengerUser](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerUser) to change the user that your app is executed as.

On a side note, you should upgrade to the latest version of Phusion Passenger, 4.0.41, for the latest bug fixes.